# Passing PHP to React while integrating it with an existing website

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently integrating React within an existing website. The website is built on top of HTML, PHP with some jQuery. Essentially at the moment, the website is juggling all of those three at once to give it some semblance of responsiveness and it's a big mess. I'm hoping I can put React to work and at least simplify some parts of it.

So, at the moment I have a PHP page. I have managed to integrate some react functionality by following [this guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-jsx-to-a-project). I have:

```
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```

Which is being rendered as a React component.

Is there any way to pass extra information to the React Component as I would while using standard React?
Something along these lines:

```
<div id="like_button_container">[object]</div>
```

So can I initialize the React component with different data depending on the page?

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way for you to do it will be to declare a `<script></script>` with the javascript data you would like to get from the react app

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.myData = { foo: 'bar'};
</script>

<div id="like_button_container">
</div>
```

Be sure that the react app is loaded after this `<script />` html tag

Comment: How would I access `window.myData` from the React app?

Comment: Nevermind, I can just access it by calling `window.myData` from React. Thank you for the help!